# First Name from database in php login form

Tags: php, login-script

I have a login form for users and admin and i want my users to be greeted by there first name after they login.

i have a table called users with the following columns `ID`, `username`, `password`, `admin`, `fname`, `lname`

i have the login script code as below and would like any help if you guys/gals can offer as i am very new to php

```
//Connect to db
include("conndb.php");
session_start();
//Get variables from login form
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
echo $username;
echo $password;
$password = MD5($password);

//query to find if user and password exist and match the password.
$query = "SELECT username, admin FROM users WHERE (username = '$username' AND password      
= '$password')";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die (mysql_error($connect));

if (mysql_num_rows($result) !=1) {
$_SESSION['loginfail'] = 1;
header ('location: index.php');
}                    

elseif (mysql_num_rows($result) ==1)
{
// check for admin flag

$a = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($a[admin] == Y)
{
 $_SESSION['admin'] = 1;
header('location: admin.php');
}
else
{
 $_SESSION['user'] = $fname;
header('location: index2.php');
}

}
```

Comment: wow, you have at least 3 things! nice to hear!

Comment: Question mark is missing I guess in your post  ;)

Comment: **What exactly** is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to

```
if ($a[admin] == Y)
{
    $_SESSION['admin'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $a['username'];
    header('location: admin.php');
}
else
{
   $_SESSION['user'] = 1;
   $_SESSION['username'] = $a['username'];
   header('location: index2.php');
}
```

Now use this $_SESSION['username'] to show user name on your web page.

Comment: done sorry still learning how to use the site :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the `username` or `id` into the session (`$_SESSION`) and in `admin.php` and `index2.php` you need to query the `fname` of the user and use it accoridingly

Answer (score 0):

You might not have started session. So start your session by adding the following line at the top of the page.

```
session_start();
```

Moreover change last part of the code as follows:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $a['username'];
if ($a['admin'] == 'Y') {
     $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
     header('location: admin.php');
}else{
     $_SESSION['user'] = true;
     header('location: index2.php');
}
```